# Delete popup windows

Tags: android, apache-flex, flash-builder, popupwindow

I am developing mobile application on flash builder 4.6
and I want to know, how to make delete popup for my delete button ?

With warning title and yes and no option ..

This is my delete button code ..

```
            protected function onDeleteButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
            NoteDatabase.deleteNote(data as Note);
            navigator.popView();  }

          <s:Button x="281" y="556" label="Delete" 
          click="onDeleteButtonClicked(event)"/>
```

Comment: How did you create the PopUp?  By delete do you mean "close"?

Comment: i meant how to show popup when i click delete button that says yes to commit the delete action and says no to cancel the action

Comment: That is a completely different issue than the one communicated in your original question.

Comment: am sry for that but could you answer this, if you dont mind ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple Alert Yes/No confirmation

code:

```
<s:Button id="deleteButton"
          x="281" y="556" 
          label="Delete" 
          click="onDeleteButtonClicked(event)"
          />
```

this will fire the function you already indicated above. All you need to do is add the code shown below:

```
protected function onDeleteButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void {
    Alert.show("do you want to delete this?", "Confirm Delete", Alert.YES | Alert.NO, null, alertListener, null, Alert.NO);
}

protected function alertListener(eventObj:CloseEvent):void {
     // Check to see if the YES button was pressed.
     if (eventObj.detail==Alert.YES) {
        NoteDatabase.deleteNote(data as Note);
        navigator.popView();  
     }
}
```

Comment: import mx.controls.Alert; could not be found

Comment: You must be using mobile.  check out this class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/SkinnablePopUpContainer.html, and add 2 simple buttons to the component.  You can then listen for the close event, and depending on the button clicked, set the "yes/no" status in a simple static property of the class which you implement the popup with.... then when it closes you check MyAlertPopup.buttonClicked==MyAlertPopup.BUTTON_YES and else it is a no.

Comment: Inline creation can be done as indicated in the other answer, however I recommend that you implement this in a separate class.  that makes it reusable in other parts of your application, and provides a consistent look and feel, in addition to promoting the good practice of re-usable code.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `SkinnablePopupContainer` on your view (where your delete button is displayed/added). Add something like this:

(*Note: This is an inline creation of a popup*)

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Component className="MyAlert">
        <s:SkinnablePopUpContainer>
            <s:Panel title="My Alert Panel">
                <s:VGroup width="100%">
                    <s:Label text="Delete" />
                    <s:Label text="Are you sure you want to delete this record?" />
                    <s:HGroup>
                        <s:Button label="Yes" click="deleteHandler();"/>
                        <s:Button label="No" click="close();"/>
                    <s:HGroup>
                </s:VGroup>
            </s:Panel>
        </s:SkinnablePopUpContainer>
    </fx:Component>
</fx:Declarations>
```

On your handler,

```
public function onDeleteButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent) : void {
    new MyAlert()).open(this, false);
}

public function deleteHandler() : void {
    //delete
}
```